# JQuery addMethod() 2 word regex validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have coded a little condition to check if value is equivalent to 1 word + 1 whitespace + 1 word, I grabbed this regex code from another article but it does not work seem to be working, could someone help me with this, I am assuming my regex is either wrong or I have some sort of error with the add method, because my jQuery Validate is working just fine validating everything else.

So basically what I need is to check for at least 2 words but obviously 1 whitespace in between the 2 words.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("twoWords", function(value, element) {
    var reg1 = /^[a-zA-Z]+\\s[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if (reg1.test(value)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    };
}, "Your signature must contain at least 2 words");

$("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
        signature: {
            required: true,
            twoWords: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        signature: {
            required: "Please select a qualification"
        }
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using forward slash as regex delimiters, you don't need to escape the backslash one more time.

```
var reg1 = /^[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+$/;
```

Within `/` delimiters, `\\s` would be treated as `\` + `s` . It won't match a white space character.

Use double baclskash only if you're using `RegExp` constructor which uses double quotes as regex delimiters.

```
var reg1 = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+\\s[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

Comment: Legend!, worked like a charm, I was scratching my head for a little while but all good now, I will tick once I can :) Thank you!

Comment: "Since you're using forward slash as delimiter," -- rather, "since you're using RegExp literals" :)

Comment: I decided to use the RegExp() JS object :)